# passing Objects, variables from ASP.net web forms to RazorView

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I currently wanted to upgrade an old ASP.NET Webforms which is using (NVelocity template) to RazorView(template) MVC is not required at the moment. BusinessLogic is already in the code behind of aspx.cs file.

Is it possible to pass Objects and Variables from Webforms to RazorViews:

I have already tried using session(Not Workerd) and querystring(Worked). passing data using Querystring works but on cost of rewriting BusinessLogic which is not an option.

Example:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myData = "DATA FROM ANOTHER UNIVERSE";
        ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();

        //Possible Function to invoke and pass data to RazorView
        RenderDataBridgeToRazorView("defaultRazorTemplate", myData);
        //Another way to look at the same functions with Objects
        RenderDataBridgeToRazorView("defaultRazorTemplate", myList);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the sentence "MVC is not required at the moment." You're going to make a lot more work for yourself by not just adopting MVC with Razor and trying to force it into "the old way." You're likely to find it's not as hard to convert as you may fear.

Comment: even if you are not using the whole MVC, you can still use razor views

Comment: which class is `Page`. which namespace?

Comment: I completely understand your point but at the moment its more kind of experimental phase. Its front-end work nothing to do with backend - Its even possible to go with Angular @dodexahedron

Comment: Its an standard webform page(default.aspx) inherited from system.web.ui.page @NevilleNazerane

Comment: MVC has nothing to do with the front end. The whole point is to separate the back end from the front end so you can more easily do whatever you want in the view. Almost every MVC application I have my team work on uses Angular in the view. Any code living in a page_load function is almost completely copy-pasteable into a controller action. A controller action is almost entirely synonymous with Page_Load (oversimplifying, but true in this context). The only difference is that you don't operate directly on controls from the C# code - you put view code in the view and leave logic in the C#.

Comment: Anecdotally, I was hesitant to switch to MVC, back in the day, but when I finally did so...OMG life has been better ever since. Literally everything is easier and faster to do, and AJAX is trivial without horrible and heavy asp.net-generated javascript and all the other cruft that web forms are seriously holding you back with. Web forms were great when they were new, but basically every other option (other than PHP :P ) is better, these days. And the learning curve is like the most gentle speed hump you've ever driven over, if that. (This message _not_ brought to you by Microsoft)

Comment: If your MVC and web forms live in the same application domain, and you're passing data between the two during a single HTTP request, a good place to store the data is [Context.Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items(v=vs.110).aspx), which is available to all modules, handlers, pages, and anything that has an HttpContext.